# How do I upload images to Firebase Storage and get link for downloadURL?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How do I upload two images to Firebase Storage and get a link for downloadURL at once... for some reason my code can only upload one Image to the database. This is my code along with the imagePicker code. Keep in mind that the second Image is optional.

```
@IBAction func pickImage1(_ sender: Any) {


    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 1

    self.present(image, animated: true)
}

//Add didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo here
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        if selected == 1 {
            myImageView1.image = image
        } else {
            myImageView2.image = image
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func pickImage2(_ sender: Any) {

       let image2 = UIImagePickerController()
    image2.delegate = self
    image2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image2.allowsEditing = false
    selected = 2

    self.present(image2, animated: true)
}




@IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {


    if let image1 = myImageView1.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return

            }


            else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString


                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL)])

             return
            }



        })
    }

    if let image2 = myImageView2.image {
        guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) else { return }

        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image1.png")
        storageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                return

            }


            else {
                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                let downloadURL2 = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])


            }

        })
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try

first getting reference to the image you want to downloadURL  using

```
let starsRef = storageRef.child("images/pic.jpg")

// Fetch the download URL
starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  }
}
```

**Reference**
[Generate a download URL SWIFT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different names for storage references. For example for second:

```
if let image2 = myImageView2.image {
    guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) else { return }

    let storageRef2 = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image1.png")
    storageRef2.putData(data, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        } else {
            let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

            self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])
        }
    })
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It still only uploads the first downloadURL